# How to change the custom option price using jQuery?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have created the three text type **custom options** and one **dropdown type custom option**. If i changed the select box value 
"**height * width**" after this calculation, I want to set the calculated result in one input box 
this all done in jQuery but now i want to set that value as custom option price
Magento.
Can you please help??

```
jQuery("#paper_size").on( "change", '#drop', function(){
var reg = jQuery('#paper_size').find("#drop").val();
 var str = jQuery('#options_3_text').val();

var str1 = jQuery('#options_2_text').val();

var total = (str * str1 * 11) + 7;

var totalmts = (str * str1 * 3.53) + 7;

if (reg == '2') {
 jQuery('#options_4_text').val(total);
}
else{

jQuery('#options_4_text').val(totalmts);

});
}
});
```

Comment: can you be a bit more descriptive about what you want. I mean if your could share the code snippet it would be great. :)

Comment: are you getting correct values in str and str1

Comment: yes I am getting correct value..

Comment: there's a bracket mismatch in your code

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work cause there was a Bracket mismatch in your code I found out after I copied the code to VS Code

```
jQuery("#paper_size").on("change", '#drop', function () {
var reg = jQuery('#paper_size').find("#drop").val();
var str = jQuery('#options_3_text').val();
var str1 = jQuery('#options_2_text').val();
var total = (str * str1 * 11) + 7;
var totalmts = (str * str1 * 3.53) + 7;
if (reg == '2') {
    jQuery('#options_4_text').val(total);
}
else {
    jQuery('#options_4_text').val(totalmts);
}});
```